# Avoid annotating all methods with @ResponseBody

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a REST api in which I return my domain objects as JSON entities.

So far I am creating a controller in which for every method I have to annotate it like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/entity/{id}", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", method=RequestMethod.GET)    
@ResponseBody
public String getEntity(@PathVariable Long id)
{
     (...)
}
```

Since all my methods in this controller are JSON entities, is there any way to hint spring that I want all methods to return `@ResponseBody` objects?
Also I have to annotate with `produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8"` because otherwise returned objects have the wrong encoding (and they are not returned as JSON).  Can I also do this for all methods instead of having to annotate each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@RequestMapping` with `produces` on type (class) level - for me it works without problems:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", produces = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
public class FooController { ... }
```

However, as you can see from [definition](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html), `@ResponseBody` can be only applied on method level in Spring 3.x.

EDIT:
As @Prancer pointed out, starting from v4.0, [Spring supports `@ResponseBody` on type level](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html).

Comment: As of Spring version 4.0, @ResponseBody can be added to the type level  which is inherited and thus DOES NOT need to be added at the method level.

Comment: @Prancer, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MichałRybak You should also mention that the Spring 4 feature only works for `@RestController`, not `@Controller`

Comment: @geoand source? From what I read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) `@RestController` is annotated with `@ResponseBody` automatically, so there is no need to annotate it once again. Also, I couldn't find any mention about `@ResponseBody` on top level not working for regular `@Controller` - this *should* work, even `@RestController` definition (mentioned above) uses this.

Comment: @MichałRybak What I meant is that when you `@RestController` you don't have to annotate anything with `@ResponseBody` since that functionality is simulated. Simply annotating a Spring 4 POJO with `@Controller` does not provide that functionality. http://www.javabeat.net/restcontroller-spring-4-0/